# install of snapd failed for xubuntu 16.04

Tags: xubuntu, snap

The message from:

```
systemctl status snapd.seeded.service
```

is:

> Failed to start Wait until snapd is fully seeded.

Any suggestions an how to debug/fix this?

Comment: After reboot, snap list is working.  snap list is returning conjure-up and other entries.

Answer (score 0):

Snap is working after the reboot.
Is there more information on the debug of snap?
When is it appropriate to reboot?

Comment: Please avoid asking questions in an answer. You can [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1045448/edit) to add more things you’d like to be answered.